# $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n-\sum _{k=1}^n\left(e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}\right)\:\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would you go about solving this limit knowing it's result but no way of proving it.

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n-\sum _{k=1}^n\left(e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}\right)\:\right)$ = $-\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can use that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{k/n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(e^{1/n^2}\right)^{k}
$$
do you see why I wrote it this way ?

Comment: It's a geometric series, so you can find an equation for the general term of the partial sums in terms of $n$. I did this and got: $S_n = \large{ \frac{\left(\exp\left({\frac{1}{n^2}}\right) - 1\right)n - \exp\left({\frac{1}{n^2}}\right) \left( \exp\left({\frac{1}{n}}\right) - 1 \right)}{\left(\exp\left({\frac{1}{n^2}}\right) - 1\right)} }.\ $ Is this correct, and what do I do next?

Comment: Yes @AdamRubinson then you have multiple way of going : Taylor Expansion for example. Have you seen it do you need another way ?

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor's theorem, $$e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}=1+\frac{k}{n^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)^2\right)=1+\frac{k}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(-\frac{k}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}\\
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\\
&=-\int_0^1x\,dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}$$